# How to authenticate external requests to WCF Web service?

Tags: web-services, authentication, soap, wsdl, .net-4.5

I'm trying to authenticate external requests to WCF Web service through the passing of user credentials in the SOAP header.

```
using (UsrService client = new UsrService())
{
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("User 1", "Password 1");
    client.SomeRemoteMethod();
}
```

I get the exception:

> Unhandled exception: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with
>   the error message: Object moved

```
Unhandled exception: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with the error message:
--
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/NuiLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f0%2fServiceModel%2fSimp
leCustomService.svc%2fsoap">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>

--.
   in System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClien
tMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall
)
   in System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodNa
me, Object[] parameters)
   in UsrService.SayHello() in c:\VS2015\Projects\WCFSharedDLL\WCFSharedDLL\TestPr
oxyClass.cs:line 44
   in ConsoleApplicationForTesting.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\VS2015\Projec
ts\ConsoleApplicationForTesting\ConsoleApplicationForTesting\Program.cs:line 1
6
```

How can I authenticate external requests to WCF Web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made in the following way.

By using transport protocol I sent user credentials as follows:

```
public const string authServiceUri = "http://localhost:8080/ServiceModel/AuthService.svc/Login";
public static CookieContainer AuthCookie = new CookieContainer();

public static bool TryLogin(string userName, string userPassword)
{
    var authRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(authServiceUri) as HttpWebRequest;
    authRequest.Method = "POST";
    authRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    authRequest.CookieContainer = AuthCookie;

    using (var requesrStream = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requesrStream))
        {
            writer.Write(@"{
                ""UserName"":""" + userName + @""",
                ""UserPassword"":""" + userPassword + @"""
            }");
        }
    }

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)authRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        if (AuthCookie.Count > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then I set CookieContainer as follows:

```
client.CookieContainer = AuthCookie;
```

After that it became possible to access the Web - service:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (UsrService client = new UsrService())
    {
        if(TryLogin("User 1", "User 1"))
        {
            client.CookieContainer = AuthCookie;
            Console.WriteLine(client.SayHello());
        }
    }
}
```